# How to clean searchText when user switches segmentController index?

Tags: swift, uisearchbar, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a searchBar in a tableView. It worked fine, until I added a segmentController. When I change segment index, searchText doesn't erases and it's obviously a bad experience.

I was trying to add a "text" property, that is equal to searchText, and do text = "", when user switches segment index. But it didn't work. I think I am using some wrong logic.

```
extension MyClass: UISearchBarDelegate {

     func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        var text = searchText
        if segmentController.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
        guard !text.isEmpty else { searchResult = data
            tableView.reloadData()
            return
        }
        searchResult = data.filter({ results -> Bool in
            results.name.contains(text)
        })
        tableView.reloadData()
        } else {
            guard !text.isEmpty else { anotherSearchResult = anotherData
                tableView.reloadData()
                return
            }
            anotherSearchResult = anotherData.filter({ results -> Bool in
                results.name.contains(text)
            })
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Solution in comments worked for me, but also, I want to add some info for those, who will search this question too. I've used func "segmentChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl)" and I added code from accepted answer: "func clearSearchBar()" to segmentController's switch statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a call `addTarget` on `segmentedController` to register a function to be called whenever the selected segment changes.

```
class MyClass: UIViewController {
    ...


    @objc func clearSearchBar() {
        searchBar.text = nil
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        segmentedControler.addTarget(self, action: #selector(clearSearchBar), for: .valueChanged)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked. Also I want to add some info for those, who will search this question too. I've used func segmentChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) and I added your code: "func clearSearchBar()" to segmentController's switch statement.

Comment: I already accepted your answer, but it seams that it doesn't resolves my question fully. Now, when I change segment to 1 - it works perfect, but when I return to 0 - it's empty, but results in table are same as it was before I changed to first index

Comment: @ArtemBoordak I think the issue is with your `searchBar(_: textDidChange:)` implementation. Did you check that `tableView.reloadData` gets called correctly? Are you updating your table view data sources correctly too?

Comment: Thank you again. I've made it by adding "searchResult = data" and "anotherSearchResult = anotherData" to method, you recommended - "clearSearchBar()"

Answer (score 1):

You need observe segmentedControl **valueChanged** method

Example below

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak private var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Observe value change
        segmentedControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(segmentedControlValueChanged), for: .valueChanged)
    }

    @objc private func segmentedControlValueChanged(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        // TODO: Clear searchbar
    }

}
```